# Jquery button click minus padding-left dont work

Tags: jquery, css, html, range

I added two buttons plus and minus; the plus works but minus doesn't work

```
$("#qqq").click(function () {
    var newValueMinus3 = parseInt($("#text2").val()) - 1;
    if (newValueMinus3 < 0) return;
    $('.lil').css("padding-left", newValueMinus3 +'px');
    // Div
});
```

Comment: Negative values are not allowed in case of css `padding`

Comment: "doesn't work" in what sense? You aren't giving enough info to reproduce or even properly understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Check for isNaN on your ParseInt before doing a math function.
2. It looks like you're referencing an ID for your click event (#qqq). 
   Your buttons need to have different id's, or else it will only wire
   up the first one.  Use a class (.qqq with an attribute
   .qqq[operator='plus']), or different id's for each button.